# Extracting the column index from table name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table(myTable) With which I am working in VBA and want to extract the column index of a particular column(col_1) so that I can use it in Cells(row,col) for further calculation.

Is it possible?
how is it done ?

Comment: Seems like it would be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the code (or bette a [mcve])? We need a more precise information about how your column is defined. How is your column determined?

Comment: Have a look at [ListColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listcolumns).  The `Index` property will give you the relative column number within the table.